# What search version do we get with Sharepoint Standard 2010.Enterprise Search or the Basic Search Center?

Tags: search

Hi all going through the below link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808863.aspx

I'm kind of confused between Enterprise Search or the Basic Search Center?
Can we get Enterprise Search with Sharepoint Standard 2010 or does it just come with 
Basic Search Center?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can compare editions here: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise search is available with the standard version of SharePoint.

Enterprise search is the one that will allow you to create content sources, schedules crawl etc... Also, you'll be able to add multiple indexer, and create a farm search topology.

Standard Search is not really configurable, and won't allow you to play with scalability.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you get the Serch Server Standart.

Have a look [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx?Capability=Search) for a feature Comparision

Comment: On your link you can see that enterprise search is available for standard version...

Comment: I have to ommit you are Right by definition.
It´s not Express or Build in Foundation Search.
One could say FAST is the Enterprise product, but you are right